# Using UndoRecord interface in MS word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, undo-redo, word-addins

Good day

I made a function in MS word to run some calculations on an opened word document that allow the user to add inputs when it is done and auto undo it when on user request using **UndoRecord** interface.

So my question is how to get the user inputs from the **undoRecord** before removing it.

```
private static void Run_Calc()
{
        Word.Application wordApp;
        Word.Document oDoc = null; int Undo_it = 0; 
        wordApp = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
        oDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
        Word.UndoRecord Un = wordApp.UndoRecord;

       //Run calculations

       Un.StartCustomRecord("Temp");

       //Waiting for user inputs here.


        DialogResult D = MessageBox.Show("Keep the inputs?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                            if (D.Equals(DialogResult.Yes))
                            {
                                Un.EndCustomRecord();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Un.EndCustomRecord(); oDoc.Undo();
                            }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `UndoRecord` doesn't contain the information you're looking for, it just marks the start and end of an undo block. Word keeps track of everything done between them, but that information is not accessible to third party devs like you and me.

If you want to store text that was entered into the document, you need to collect it from the body of the document before calling `Undo`. E.g.:

```
// get text of each paragraph
Paragraphs paras = oDoc.Paragraphs;
foreach (Paragraph para in paras)
{
    Range paraRange = para.Range;
    string paraText = paraRange.Text;
    // do something with it
}
```